# Behavior of Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I cannot find anything on this... I am wondering when I have a fragment within an activity why I can't call certain things such as getPackageName(), and getContentResolver()?

Comment: because these methods are not from Fragment...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call from a non static function inside the fragment, after it attaches to the activity.

```
    getActivity().getPackageName();
    getActivity().getContentResolver();
```

As your commenter stated, these are not fragment functions, you have to get the contextWrapper instance.

Answer (score 1):

Because as per [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), the methods you mentioned are methods of the Context class. Activity is a subclass of Context, therefore it has these methods available. Fragment, however, is not. There are 2 ways to get hold of these methods from a fragment:

First option: After your fragment has been attached (it's onAttach() method has been called) you can use the getActivity() method to get the activity that it has been attached to. Then you can use getPackageName() and getContentResolver(). Such as this: getActivity().getPackageName(). To be extra safe, you might want to do:

```
Activity myActivity = getActivity();
if (myActivity != null)
{
    myActivity.getPackageName();
    myActivity.getContentResolver();
}
else
{
    //deal with the null problem
}
```

Second option: In the onCreateView() method, your fragment won't yet be attached so you can't use the above method. You may use the LayoutInflater to get a View. Then call getContext() on the view. Such as this:

```
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
myView.getContext().getPackageName();
myView.getContext().getContentResolver();
```